# Confusion regarding Producers and Consumers in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I am working on a existing project and using kafka to fetch some data from DB(for generating reports). I have some questions. Which may sound silly to many(Sorry for that). I am mentioning the steps which I have performed till now.

1. Installed Confluent
2. Started Zookeeper, Kafka and Schema Registry
3. I had downloaded MySql connectors jars and copied to kafka-connect-jdbc
4. Then made a mysql properties file with connection url, topic-prefix etc.
5. The I started the mysql connector using this command 
   **bin/connect-standalone     etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-mysql.properties**
6. After this if I run the avro consumer command in terminal using this command 
    **bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic mysql-01 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning**

   it gives data succesfully.

Now, the problem and confusion.
 I want to get the same data by using Spring Boot.
 I am writing code only for consumer. **Do I need a Producer here**??(As per my understanding goes, I have data already in my topic, I just need to fetch that)
I have made an avro schema for that as well. It gets deserialized as well but I don't get the data.

The data which get printed in terminal is:

```
{"cust_code":27,"cust_description":{"string":"Endline survey completed"}}
```

The data in Spring Boot console is:

```
{"cust_code": "cust_description":{"string":""}}
```